# iOS iPhone App Hamburger Menu Button Size

Tags: interface-design, ios

I've decided to add a Hamburger Menu on my new iOS iPhone Application.
So in order to successfully implement that I need to prepare few images specially for the Hamburger button.

But I couldn't find specific sizes which are suitable for this. Can anybody guide me? Currently I have designed images in following sizes:

1. 44px - @1x.png

   [image]
2. 44px - @2x.png

   [image]
3. 66px - @3x.png

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

The sizes for custom navigation bar icons are listed in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines here: [iOS Human Interface Guidelines — Custom Icons](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/)

The sizes are listed as:

```
iPad Pro, iPad, iPad mini         About 44px by 44px
iPhone 6s, iPhone 6, iPhone SE    About 44px by 44px
iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 6 Plus     About 66px by 66px
```

The difference is because the iPhone 6[s] Plus uses the @3x resources while the others use the @2x images. So your @2x and @3x sizes are correct, your @1x image should however be half the size of your @2x image.

From [iOS Human Interface Guidelines — Image Size and Resolution](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/):

> [image]
>
> ...
>
> A standard resolution image has a scale factor of 1.0 and is referred to as an @1x image. High resolution images have a scale factor of 2.0 or 3.0 and are referred to as @2x and @3x images. Suppose you have a standard resolution @1x image that’s 100px by 100px, for example. The @2x version of this image would be 200px by 200px. The @3x version would be 300px by 300px.

Now, there aren't many iDevices left that use @1x images that you're likely to support so it may not practically be an issue, but it's something you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to read the Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/). If this is too much I'd recommend to read at least these sections: [Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/navigation/), [Navigation Bars](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/) and [Tab Bars](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/).

The reason why I refer to these documents is, that there is no Design Pattern like the Navigation Drawer and Hamburger Menu in the iOS UI ecosystem. I tend to recommend designers to stick to the UI design patterns the target Operating System provide. I think it's easier for the users to find their way through the app using known or OS specific patterns.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently Apple don't provide measurements for UI elements (anymore?). But from Google Material design and elsewhere measurements for ideal button size can be obtained. From [Material Design's Metrics & Keylines](https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size):

> To ensure balanced information density and usability, touch targets should be at least 48 x 48 dp. In most cases, there should be 8dp or more space between them.
>
> Size elements at least 48dp high and wide to ensure a physical size of about 9mm regardless of screen size. The recommended target size for touchscreen objects is 7-10mm.

Where dp is [density independent pixel](https://material.google.com/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-density-independent-pixels-dp). How this translates to retina displays, I'm not sure. Is it 46 px on @1x, 92 px on @2x and 138 px on @3x?